# Python web scraper freezes at 520 urls feeded. Whats wrong with it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, freeze

1. Example urls.csv to be fed to the web scraper.

```
Main,Income statement,Balance sheet,Cash flows
https://www.investing.com/equities/vical-inc,https://www.investing.com/equities/vical-inc-income-statement,https://www.investing.com/equities/vical-inc-balance-sheet,https://www.investing.com/equities/vical-inc-cash-flow
```

2. ncav.py is the actual web scraper.

```
from os import system, name

from time import sleep

from csv import reader, writer

from ncavfunctions import income, flashbalance


def clear():
    """Clears GUI.

    """
    if name == 'nt':
        _ = system('cls')
    else:
        _ = system('clear')

# Try to read urls.csv. country is a list of lists of strings
try:
    with open('urls.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = reader(csvfile)
        next(csv_reader)    # Skip Headers
        country = []
        for line in csv_reader:
            country.append(
                [line[0],
                line[1],
                line[2],
                line[3]])
    print("0. urls.csv loaded")
except:
    print("Error with urls.csv file!")
    sleep(5)

# Construct country_ncav a list of tuples of strings
country_ncav = []
i = 1
for line in country:
    clear()
    loading_perc = i * 100 / len(country)
    print("Processed {0:.2f}".format(loading_perc), "% of urls")
    print("Processing...")
    i = i + 1
    try:
        lst = \
        income(line[1])\
        + flashbalance(line[2])
        country_ncav.append(lst)
    except:
        country_ncav.append(["Unknown Error"])

# Save a csv log of country ncav items.
header = ['Name', 'Shares', 'Last price',
'Total current assets', 'Total Liabilities']
with open('flashncav.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = writer(csvfile)
    csv_writer.writerow(header)
    csv_writer.writerows(country_ncav)

print("Closing in 5 seconds")
sleep(4)
print("Enjoy!")
sleep(1)
```

3. The ncavfunctions module is the following.

```
"""investing.com rejects get requests not identifying a User-Agent
1. Copy url to clipboard
2. Open Google Chrome, right click open space and click inspect
3. In Dev window click Network Tab
4. Paste url in Address Bar and press Enter, wait fully load
5. At Name window click info, on the right click Headers
6. Scroll Down to User-Agent and copy
7. Paste it between "" after "User-Agent": in var headers
8. Continue lines as needed

Parsing for investing.com
html.parser : prettify() encoding issues
lxml        : prettify() encoding issues
lxml-xml    : prettify() working but how grab from xml?
xml         : prettify() working but how grab from xml?
html5lib    : prettify() encoding isssues
Using html5, prettify() doesnt work due to encoding issues, but
i can grab the elements i want from soup element
"""
from requests import get

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10\
_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 \
Safari/537.36"}

def indusector(url_m):
    """Returns industry and sector from all known types of mains.

    Keyword arguments:
    url_m -- The url of company's main page.
    """
    global inse
    try:
        inse = indusector_a(url_m)
    except:
        inse = (
            "Error main page or data N/A",
            "")
    return inse

def indusector_a(url_m):
    """Returns industry and sector of company from type a main url.

    url_m -- The url of company's main page.
    """
    resp = get(url_m, headers=headers)
    page = soup(resp.content, "html5lib")
    cont_a = page.find("div", class_="companyProfileHeader")
    cont_b = cont_a.find_all("a")
    industry = cont_b[0].string
    sector = cont_b[1].string
    return industry, sector

def income(url_i):
    """Returns all NCAV items from all known type income statements.

    Keyword arguments:
    url_i -- The url of the Income statement.
    """
    try:
        inc = income_a(url_i)
    except:
        try:
            inc = income_b(url_i)
        except:
            inc = (
                "Error income statement or data n/a",
                "",
                "")
    return inc

def income_a(url_i):
    """Returns all NCAV items from income statements type a.

    Keyword arguments:
    url_i -- The url of the Income statement.
    """
    resp = get(url_i, headers=headers)
    page = soup(resp.content, "html5lib")

    # Grab secondaries from js dialog box and Diluted weighted average
    # shares
    cont_a = page.find_all("tbody")
    cont_b = cont_a[2].find_all("tr")
    cont_c = cont_b[31].find_all("td")
    shares = cont_c[1].string

    # Grab last price
    cont_a = page.find(id="last_last")
    lprice = cont_a.string

    # Grab Name
    cont_a = page.find("h1", class_="float_lang_base_1 relativeAttr")
    namet = cont_a.string
    tcut = len(namet) - 1
    name = namet[0:tcut]

    return name, shares, lprice

def income_b(url_i):
    """Returns all NCAV items from income statements type b.

    Keyword arguments:
    url_i -- The url of the Income statement.
    """
    resp = get(url_i, headers=headers)
    page = soup(resp.content, "html5lib")
    cont_a = page.find_all("tbody")
    cont_b = cont_a[1].find_all("tr")  # [1]vs[2] is the difference
    cont_c = cont_b[31].find_all("td") # between the 2 types.
    shares = cont_c[1].string
    cont_a = page.find(id="last_last")
    lprice = cont_a.string
    cont_a = page.find("h1", class_="float_lang_base_1 relativeAttr")
    namet = cont_a.string
    tcut = len(namet) - 1
    name = namet[0:tcut]
    return name, shares, lprice

def balance(url_b):
    """Returns all NCAV items from all known type Balance sheets.

    Keyword arguments:
    url_b -- The url of the Balance sheet.
    """
    try:
        bal = balance_a(url_b)
    except:
        bal = (
            "Error balance sheet or data n/a",
            "", "",
            "", "",
            "", "")
    return bal

def balance_a(url_b):
    """Returns all NCAV items from Balance sheet type a.

    Keyword arguments:
    url_b -- The url of the Balance sheet.
    """
    resp = get(url_b, headers=headers)
    page = soup(resp.content, "html5lib")

    # Grab bolds of js dialog box
    cont_a = page.find_all(id="parentTr")

    # Grab last total current assets
    cont_b = cont_a[0].find_all("td")
    last_tot_curr_ass = cont_b[1].string

    # Grab last total liabilities
    cont_b = cont_a[3].find_all("td")
    last_tot_liabs = cont_b[1].string

    # Grab secondaries of js dialog box
    cont_a = page.find_all("tr", class_="child")

    # Grab last cash
    cont_b = cont_a[1].find_all("td")
    last_cash = cont_b[1].string

    # Grab last cash & equivalents
    cont_b = cont_a[2].find_all("td")
    last_casnnequins = cont_b[1].string

    # Grab accounts receivables
    cont_b = cont_a[5].find_all("td")
    last_accreceivs = cont_b[1].string

    # Grab last inventory
    cont_b = cont_a[6].find_all("td")
    last_invs = cont_b[1].string

    # Grab last total debt
    cont_b = cont_a[27].find_all("td")
    last_tot_dts = (cont_b[1].string)

    return (
        last_tot_curr_ass, last_cash,
        last_casnnequins, last_accreceivs,
        last_invs, last_tot_liabs,
        last_tot_dts)

def cashflow(url_c):
    """Returns opcash and capex from Statement of cash flows all types.

    Keyword arguments:
    url_c -- The url of the Statement of cash flows.
    """
    try:
        cas = cashflow_a(url_c)
    except:
        cas = (
            "Error cash flow statement or data n/a", "",
            "", "",
            "", "",
            "", "")

    return cas

def cashflow_a(url_c):
    """Returns opcash and capex from Statement of cash flows type a.

    Keyword arguments:
    url_c -- The url of the Statement of cash flows.
    """
    resp = get(url_c, headers=headers)
    page = soup(resp.content, "html5lib")

    # Grab bolds of js dialog box and incremental operating income
    cont_a = page.find_all(id="parentTr")

    cont_b = cont_a[0].find_all("td")
    incr_opcash_4 = cont_b[1].string
    incr_opcash_3 = cont_b[2].string
    incr_opcash_2 = cont_b[3].string
    incr_opcash_1 = cont_b[4].string

    # Grab secondaries of js dialog box and incremental capital
    # expenditures
    cont_a = page.find_all("tr", class_="child")
    cont_b = cont_a[9].find_all("td")
    incr_capex_4 = cont_b[1].string
    incr_capex_3 = cont_b[2].string
    incr_capex_2 = cont_b[3].string
    incr_capex_1 = cont_b[4].string

    return (
        incr_opcash_4, incr_opcash_3,
        incr_opcash_2, incr_opcash_1,
        incr_capex_4, incr_capex_3,
        incr_capex_2, incr_capex_1)

def lastprice(url_i):
    """Returns last price from all known type income statements.

    Keyword arguments:
    url_i -- The url of the Income statement.
    """
    try:
        lprice = lastprice_a(url_i)
    except:
        try:
            lprice = lastprice_b(url_i)
        except:
            lprice = ("iError", "iError")
    return lprice

def lastprice_a(url_i):
    """Returns last price from income statements type a.

    Keyword arguments:
    url_i -- The url of the Income statement.
    """
    resp = get(url_i, headers=headers)
    page = soup(resp.content, "html5lib")

    # Grab last price
    cont_a = page.find(id="last_last")
    lprice = cont_a.string

    return lprice

def flashbalance(url_b):
    """Returns all NCAV items from all known type Balance sheets.

    Keyword arguments:
    url_b -- The url of the Balance sheet.
    """
    try:
        flashbal = flashbalance_a(url_b)
    except:
        flashbal = ("Error balance sheet or data n/a", "")
    return flashbal

def flashbalance_a(url_b):
    """Returns all NCAV items from Balance sheet type a.

    Keyword arguments:
    url_b -- The url of the Balance sheet.
    """
    resp = get(url_b, headers=headers)
    page = soup(resp.content, "html5lib")

    # Grab bolds of js dialog box
    cont_a = page.find_all(id="parentTr")

    # Grab last total current assets
    cont_b = cont_a[0].find_all("td")
    last_tot_curr_ass = cont_b[1].string

    # Grab last total liabilities
    cont_b = cont_a[3].find_all("td")
    last_tot_liabs = cont_b[1].string

    return (last_tot_curr_ass, last_tot_liabs)
```

4. Example output flashncav.csv

```
Name,Shares,Last price,Total current assets,Total Liabilities
Vical Inc (BBI),2.94,1.4700,30.73,13.14
```

5. The problem is that if the csv file contains more than 130 rows, ncav.py freezes.
   The current solution is to manually break the urls.csv (sometimes 2000 companies)
   to groups of 130 rows. Any better ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One option is to try another method for reading the csv file like Pandas [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: The list country_ncav seems to be the bottleneck of my scraper. Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are overloading your memory. As a first step, I would use a command like top in linux to monitor how the memory does, while the script is running. 
If running out of memory is the issue, one thing that could make it better, would be not to append the results in the country_ncav list, but directly writing them into the file, by appending them line by line.

As a recommendation in general, try to use already existing scraping libraries or frameworks, like scrapy, it will make it easier and more performing, unless this is a task to create your own scraper.

Comment: Is the windows 10 task manager to be trusted for memory monitoring? It jumped from 27ish to 40% when i ran it and python was top user

Comment: Well said! Very helpful insight! Commenting out the country_ncav.append(lst) made possible for the scraper to digest all the urls (I stopped at 800). Im gonna try directrly writing line by line to new csv. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The following code did the trick after the notional solution above.
New ncav.py:

```
from time import sleep

from csv import reader, writer

from ncavfunctions import income, flashbalance


# Try to read urls.csv. country is a list of lists of strings.
try:
    with open('urls.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = reader(csvfile)
        next(csv_reader)    # Skip Headers
        country = []
        for line in csv_reader:
            country.append(
                [line[0],
                line[1],
                line[2],
                line[3]])
    print("File urls.csv loaded.")
except:
    print("Error loading urls.csv file!")
    sleep(5)

# Initiate csv log.
try:
    header = ['Name', 'Shares', 'Last price',
    'Total current assets', 'Total Liabilities']
    with open('ncav.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = writer(csvfile)
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
    print("File ncav.csv succesfully initiated.")
except:
    print("Error initiating ncav.csv")

# Update csv log.
i = 1
for line in country:
    loading_perc = i * 100 / len(country)
    print("Processed {0:.2f}".format(loading_perc), "% of urls")
    print("Processing...")
    i = i + 1
    try:
        lst = \
        income(line[1])\
        + flashbalance(line[2])
        with open('ncav.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
            csv_writer = writer(csvfile)
            csv_writer.writerow(lst)
        print("Company info saved.")
    except:
        print("Error saving company info.")

print("Quiting in 5 seconds")
sleep(4)
print("Enjoy!")
sleep(1)
```